# SSIS Lookup Transformation

Tags: ssis

I am working on a project with SSIS and would like to know if situation is possible to handle using the Lookup Transformation.

I have an input stream with values something like

- NAME1
- NAME2
- NAME3
- ALL

I want to lookup these values in a master table which has only names and NOT "ALL" value. But I want to pass the records with ALL too. How can I pass the lookup values for few known values where there will be no match?

If not lookup, please suggest me some other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **NoMatchBehavior** property in a Lookup component on how to handle rows without a match. You can set it with the editor (it's a dropdown on the General tab) or with the Properties window of the component.

For your scenario there are two options:

- *Ignore failure* and keep them in the same stream. The lookup output column's values will all be NULL.
- *Redirect the no match rows* into another stream. Again, the values will be NULL, but you can handle them differently if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. I might have missed to say this : The input stream may have value which actually may not match in master table. Such records I have to handle separately. I just have to include ALL value to pass the lookup. Can I use this in query for lookup ? or can i manually add this ALL value in query ?

Answer (score 0):

In master table table insert `NA` Name with other attributes `NA`. When you lookup Set `Ignore Failure` on how to handle no match entries. Then you get `NULL` values for not matching Names, so insert Derived Column element and replace `NULL` values with your new PrimaryKey of `NA` Name.